# Union of Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, hamiltonian-path

If we have two Hamiltonian graphs =(,) and ′=(,′) that are on the same set of ≥5 vertices and do not share any edges. Is the union of ′and  also Hamiltonian?

Comment: Take a hamiltonian cycle in $H$. Is that cycle still hamiltonian in $H\cup H'$?

Comment: Well I'm not sure about how to check it

Comment: @Sasha121 going from tjeremie's point, Let that cycle in $H$ be $C={e_1, e_2, ..., e_n}$. Are those edges still in $H \cup H'$?

Comment: @roundsquare They're on the same set, so I think it might be the case

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $G$ the graph which is the union of $H$ and $H'$.

The vertices of $G$ are V and the edges of $G$ are $E \cup E'$.

$H$ is Hamiltonian so there is a cycle $C=\{e_1, e_2, ..., e_n\}$ which (a) visits every vertex in $V$; and (b) each $e_i$ is in $E$.

So let's look at $C$ in $G$. It is still true that it (a) visits every vertex in $V$; and (b) each $e_i$ is in $E \cup E'$. So $C$ is a cycle in $G$ so $G$ is Hamiltonian.